# JPA and Derby Performance

Tags: java, performance, jpa, derby

I wrote an application using JPA. The application makes around 5 or 6 inserts per second on one Table. The insert is done by a simple Transaction begin, persist and transaction commit.

With this approach the application has a really heavy cpu load (around 80%). Using the JVisualVM i profiled the application and came to this result:

[image: jvisualvm]

This shows that around 30% percent of the time is spent in writing and flushing to Log Files.
Also the `setExclusive` method has a load of 14% of the time.

Is there a way to optimize this? Maybe disabling logging?

Comment: It's not writing just logging of information for debugging purposes but probably writing a transaction log. If you disable this logging mechanism you might get corrupted or inconsistent data. What you could try to do is using some kind of batching to reduce amount of transactions. So 'Transaction Begin' multiple persist operations and then transaction commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enterbios is right. Disable the logging and you don’t have a database anymore, but simply SQL for writing to files (bye bye acid). As most databases do, Derby uses group commit, i.e. that the log for multiple transactions are grouped in a single disk write. But if you do a single update, commit, wait and then another insert the the group commit will have very little effect as there is only log from a single insert to write.

The setExclusive time points to contention for the same data (multiple threads accessing the same database page).